Matlab for loop speed depends on iterator declaration
I tested these two ways to loop over an iterator variable, and I would like to know why the performances are so different. The only difference is the declaration of the range, first in a separated variable, last directly in the loop.
clear all;

tic 
a = 1:1:1e6;
b = 0;
for i = a
    b = b + i;
end
toc


tic
c = 0;
for j = 1:1:1e6
    c = c + j;
end
toc

The elapsed time is ~0.012s for the first method and ~0.003 for the second.
I'm on Matlab R2021a.

The difference is probably caused by the fact that the first version creates the array 1:1:1e6, whereas the second doesn't. The current documentation is not clear about this, but typing help for in the command window will tell you that (tested on R2024a; emphasis mine)

Long loops are more memory efficient when the colon expression appears
in the for statement since the index vector is never created.

You can also read about this in a blog post by Loren Shure.
As a side note, using tic and toc is not the best way to time code. It is better to use timeit.

Interesting example in that blog post that you can loop for j = 1:Inf because the index array is never created... can't think of an example where I'd want that but I'm sure there is one!

@Wolfie Also, it issues a waning that it will only do 2^63 iterations

@Wolfie Similar to while true.

@Cris indeed, maybe I should have said I'd always just use a while for that, but I guess it gives you an indexing variable for "free"
